# Thunar - can I change the sorting method for one specific folder?

Tags: xfce, thunar

- Xubuntu 13.10
- Thunar 1.6.3

Is it possible to change the sorting method for one specific folder only?

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: You seem to be right, it's not possible with Thunar 1.6.3 (which is in XFCE 4.10).

Comment: @vasa1 After further research, it is indeed correct that it's impossible. Please do submit your comment as a reply so I can mark it as solved. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find a current official link indicating that it is *not* possible to sort one folder differently than the rest but a similar feature was requested quite a while back: http://mail.xfce.org/pipermail/thunar-dev/2006-September/003425.html.

Comment: Same here, can't find any official statement. But I have found plenty of posts where users ask about it and not one single post confirming the opposite, that it is possible.

Comment: I was hoping to find it possible via the command line but `man thunar` doesn't offer such an option. I guess if you really want to nail this one, asking on [Xubuntu's dev mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/xubuntu-devel) would be one way.